# The following packages have unmet dependencies!

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, aptitude

I am writing this because I am very confused about installing PostgreSQL 9.3 on my Ubuntu 14.04.
First I need it for my Python/Django development, and I ran into the problem when I tried to install it.
Now I have this error and it is driving me crazy:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgresql-9.3 : Depends: postgresql-client-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: postgresql-common (>= 142~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have found some solutions online ([How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)),  and I did everything to the Preventive Measures part, because I have had some broken packages problem, and again after I had this error show to me again.

The second thing I have followed the official PostgreSQL installing tutorial (http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/), and I have had duplicated repositories, but I have deleted them and I have added a fresh one but still this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me share with other people my experience with installing `postgresql-9.3`. First of all I have been struggling with this for about 4/5 days, and I finally manage to do it.

All went wrong with these nasty errors I have shared in my first post, as I have tried to google it and discover that people have more less the same error, or struggling to solve a similar one.

Long story short, you have a very nice answer here how to resolve unmet packages:

[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

My mistake was that I have made duplicated repository, and the answer in this link solved that, this 
command `sudo apt-get install -f` just made another error, you must do this manually, at least I did it (read to the section Preventive Measures, but you could read to the end, it is an imba post).

Second I manage to google this post from official PostgreSQL page 
http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20140327084212.GA12703@msgid.df7cb.de (this is the error people usually have when they are struggling with installation of postgresql), this led me to
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt, this is the proper way for adding PostgreSQL Packages to your system, just read it and do it step by step.

Third step are series of commands provided in the @vembutech post:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3
```

Answer (score 72):

You can install the package using.

make sure the repo sources are up to date

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To Install the package.

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

Once the package determines that you have some missing dependencies, run the following command to fix broken or missing dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Above command will only download the missing dependencies if you have already installed the package.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it meant use `sudo apt-get install -f packagename` and was getting the same error.

Comment: This doesn't work with **python2.7-minimal** errors.

Comment: Doesn't work: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`

Comment: work! ubuntu 20

Comment: @JBSnorro did you find the solution then?

Answer (score 64):

I know I'm a bit late, but none of the above solutions worked for me. What really solved my problem was to use `aptitude` instead of apt-get. `aptitude` will suggest resolutions to the problem.

Simply run these:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude install <package-name>
```

`aptitude` will suggest dependencies resolution for you e.g:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libyaml-dev [Not Installed]                        

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/? (n)

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Downgrade the following packages:                                
1)     libyaml-0-2 [0.1.4-3ubuntu3.1 (now) -> 0.1.4-3ubuntu3 (trusty)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] (Y)
```

as discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35679746/7183373).

Comment: This worked for me while the other answers didn't. Thanks!

Comment: The crucial thing for me was that `aptitude` was willing to suggest *downgrading* packages whereas `apt` was not. This offered me the solution of removing a third-party package from a PPA and resetting it to the stock Ubuntu version which fixed all my dependency issues.

Comment: This worked for me while the others did not. Just wondering now why this isn't the standard tool. It's so much more user friendly than just saying "I can't" without a reasoning why.

Comment: That's a life saver :)

Comment: genius , Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes the dependencies that need fixing are unrelated to the program you are trying to install.
In my case it was giving off this error:

> The following have unmet dependecies
>
> shashlik : Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: lib32z1 but it is not going to be installed

It turned out that I had tried to install a program called "Shashlik" and the installation had failed.
So I ran the code:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove shashlik
```

And then I ran:

```
sudo apt install autoconf
```

This seemed to fix the error as my program then installed.
I am not sure how much the second command helped but I put it there in case it was necessary for the solution to work.

Comment: how did you determine this was the issue?

Comment: At the risk of replying late, the error was given to me when I tried to install the package, I just had to read the error message.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you've to find the package that is broken. Let's say you're getting following error,

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.9 : Depends: libpython3.9-stdlib (= 3.9.5-3~20.04.1) but 3.9.4-1+bionic1 is to be installed
```

You've to manually remove the files of broken package.

To get the list of the files you can run

```
sudo ls –l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i libpython3.9-dev
```

Replace `libpython3.9-dev` with your own package name.

Output

```
libpython3.9-dev:amd64.list
libpython3.9-dev:amd64.md5sums
```

Now, you can to discard these files.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.9-dev*
```

Perform the same operations for the rest of packages.

Once it's done, you can run

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

This time the above command should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try by installing the with below command.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common=151.pgdg12.4+1

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3
```

Comment: "E: Version '151.pgdg12.4+1' for 'postgresql-common' was not found", error again...

Comment: I manage to do it, I run second command and finally I did it, @vembutech <3