# How do I remove manually installed libpcap0.8?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

A few day ago I have installed `libpcap0.8-dev` but after that I installed `libpcap0.8_1.4.0-2_amd64.deb` and now I have tried almost of way to remove it but I can't! Since that, I can't install any package!!!

here is code:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpcap0.8
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpcap0.8
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/110 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13,3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 204351 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcap0.8_1.5.3-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcap0.8:amd64 (1.5.3-2) over (1.4.0-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.5.3-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz', which is different from other instances of package libpcap0.8:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcap0.8_1.5.3-2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I do:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libpcap0.8-dev:i386 libpcap0.8:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libpcap0.8-dev:i386' is not installed, so not removed. Did you mean 'libpcap0.8-dev'?
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcap0.8-dev : Depends: libpcap0.8 (= 1.5.3-2) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And if I just type `sudo apt-get purge libpcap0.8-dev`

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libpcap0.8-dev
[sudo] password for mark: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcap-dev : Depends: libpcap0.8-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libpcap0.8 : Breaks: libpcap0.8:i386 (!= 1.4.0-2) but 1.5.3-2 is to be installed
 libpcap0.8:i386 : Breaks: libpcap0.8 (!= 1.5.3-2) but 1.4.0-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: What happens with just `sudo apt-get purge libpcap0.8-dev`?

Comment: Thanks for answer @Wilf, i have answered your question above! thanks for help!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/563178/295286) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/295286)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Serg for answer my questions! Well,, I have resolved this, and this is easy to resolved. I post here for anyone has the same propblem! Here:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge libpcap0.8-dev libpcap0.8:i386 libpcap-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libpcap-dev* libpcap0.8:i386* libpcap0.8-dev*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 75 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1.034 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 204350 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libpcap0.8:i386 (1.5.3-2) ...
Purging configuration files for libpcap0.8:i386 (1.5.3-2) ...
Removing libpcap-dev (1.5.3-2) ...
Removing libpcap0.8-dev (1.5.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpcap0.8:amd64 (1.4.0-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.5) ...
```

It's so simple.
Just `sudo apt-get purge libpcap0.8-dev libpcap0.8:i386 libpcap-dev`.