# Unmet dependencies libsdl1.2

Tags: package-management

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl1.2-dev : Depends: libx11-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libasound2-dev
                 Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcaca-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxext-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

so I typed in:

```
evan@evan-XPS-13-9350:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
and this was the output: Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/563178/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies/563319#563319?

Comment: I have tried install -f and it says I have 0 things but it still says I haveheld broken packages

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the command and the output. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: as you can see it says 0 for all

Comment: Looks fine.  No more held/broken packages. Congratulations~ ;-)

Comment: But it still will not install. I type in: sudo apt-get install -f mercurial libsdl1.2-dev but get out:  the original thing i posted

Comment: You can fine the libsdl1.2-dev package for your release here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libsdl1.2-dev&searchon=names I cannot find a package named mecurial