# pgadmin3 has disappeared?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, postgresql

In order to learn Linux I built a small Linux machine. A week ago I installed posrgresql and pgadmin3. All worked fine. Today it seems that pgadmin3 has disappeared. I tried to "find it back" with `sudo find / -name pgadmin3* -print`. `whereis pgadmin3` returns `/usr/share/pgadmin3`. There is a `/usr/share/pgadmin3` directory but it contains no executable `pgadmin3`, it contains other files though.

I tried a reinstall and got the message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pgadmin3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pgadmin3 : Depends: libwxbase3.0-0 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did the following to recover as [per this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563178/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies):

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

apt next suggested to remove the dependencies and I did so, but the error persists. My questions:

- is it possible to recover pgadmin3?
- if not, how can I overcome this frustrating install error?
- something I can hardly expect an answer for, but what have I done to create this mess?

Postgres (9.5) still works and with `psql` I can query the database. I use Mint/Mate 18.1. Postgres and pgadmin3 were installed from repository: `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main`.

All suggestions are very welcome. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you have unmet dependencies ,Use `aptitude` to install the package as it will suggest the solution to unmet dependencies problems

install `aptitude` via apt `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

then install the package:

`sudo aptitude install pgadmin3`

where `aptitude` will suggest the solutions to resolve the problem,what you should do is to choose the right one that you think will solve your problem.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Still curious what caused this problem, but I can work now :-)