# Cant install anything - The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management

Just about anything I try to install via the package manager gets the following:

```
root@opsview-appliance:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get install make
  Reading package lists... Done 
  Building dependency tree 
  Reading state information... Done 
  make is already the newest version. 
  You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: 
  The following packages have unmet dependencies.  
    linux-image-virtual : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic but it is not going to be installed 
  E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Even when using -f its more of the same:

```
root@opsview-appliance:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# apt-get -f install make 
  Reading package lists... Done 
  Building dependency tree 
  Reading state information... Done 
  make is already the newest version. 
  You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these: 
  The following packages have unmet dependencies.  
    linux-image-virtual : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic but it is not going to be installed 
  E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestion ? `apt-get -f install` What is the output of this ? Did you add any repositories?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The following packages have unmet dependencies!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563178/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: Of course. did not work. Also came across that other thread. Nothing there worked either.

Comment: and what about my other two questions?

Comment: This is a packaged VM for opsview so it came with their repos (I didnt touch it). It used to work flawlessly.
apt-get -f gives me the exact same results with linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic dependency.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` to update your package database?

Comment: I have and it did not work.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f` like RoVo suggested? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not this is what solved the problem:

```
apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-106-generic
```

I should mention that I also had to extend the /boot partition as it didnt allow me to install anything without it.

Comment: You've probably got old kernels installed that you no longer need and [can be removed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu).