# ubuntu 16: having trouble installing ffmpeg (latest version)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, ffmpeg

`Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS` and trying to install ffmpeg.

```
$ sudo apt install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:4.1.3-0york1~16.04).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-1 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.1.243) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-samples-10-1 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.1.243) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-visual-tools-10-1 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.1.243) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It says ffmpeg is already the newest version, which it is not (V1.4 is the most current one afaik). I tried checking ffmpeg version:

```
$ ffmpeg -version
The program 'ffmpeg' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Note: I looked over other posts and added this apt repo:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4`

I was able to install ffmpeg using pip3 and that installed to 
`/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ffmpeg`.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: A couple of things: 1. Did you run `sudo apt-get -f install` as it's telling you to do? 2. The phrase "newest version" in the output *doesn't* stand for the absolutely newest version of the application, but the newest version *from the repositories you currently have added to your system*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The following packages have unmet dependencies!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563178/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: I did run that, but that throws a weird error: Preparing to unpack .../libcublas-dev
Unpacking libcublas-dev (10.2.1.243-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas-dev_10.2.1.243-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas_static.a', which is also in package nvidia-cuda-dev 7.5.18-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas-dev_10.2.1.243-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to build this from [sources](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

```
$ tar xjf ffmpeg-4.2.1.tar.bz2
$ cd ffmpeg-4.2.1
```

And use instructions from `INSTALL.md` file:

1. Type `./configure` to create the configuration. A list of configure
   options is printed by running `configure --help`.

   `configure` can be launched from a directory different from the FFmpeg
   sources to build the objects out of tree. To do this, use an absolute
   path when launching `configure`, e.g. `/ffmpegdir/ffmpeg/configure`.
2. Then type `make` to build FFmpeg. GNU Make 3.81 or later is required.
3. Type `make install` to install all binaries and libraries you built.