# Ubuntu Server 20.04 - Raspberry Pi 4 - Unmet Dependencies libjson-c-dev

Tags: apt, dependencies, raspberrypi, arm

I'm trying to install Netdata on my Raspberry Pi 4 using Ubuntu Server 20.04. At some point I get the following unmet dependicies error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjson-c-dev : Depends: libjson-c4 (= 0.13.1+dfsg-7) but 0.13.1+dfsg-7ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

When going to the Ubuntu packages website I do see the package being listed for Arm64, but there is no website to download it from: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libjson-c-dev

Does anybody know how to install libjson-c-dev on the Raspberry Pi 4?

Thanks!

Comment: Fix your *held broken packages* first. Apt won't work until you remove the package (and perhaps source) you introduced that broke your package management logic. Trying to workaround or ignoring the problem will only make it worse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The following packages have unmet dependencies!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563178/the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependencies)